# What's the idiomatic translation of "I appreciate it" that expresses gratefulness?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

Update: "to appreciate" has multiple meanings, I'm specifically interested in the one that expresses gratefulness; quoting Wiktionary:

> To be grateful or thankful for.

Some relevant translation of "appreciate" I've found are "<etw. Akk> schätzen", "sich <etw. Gen> bewusst sein", "für <etw. Akk> dankbar sein" and the phrase "sehr nett von Ihnen/dir".

What construct can be used where I would say "I appreciate it" to emphasize that I'm especially thankful for a favour in English? I'm interested in both an informal situation ("I appreciate you walking the dog this morning, honey") and in a formal setting ("I appreciate you preparing the documents in advance to speed up the negotiations").

Comment: Can you add some idiomatic examples of that phrase in context? Non-native speakers of English might not be familiar enought with the connotations, pragramtics, etc.

Comment: What remains unclear after having looked at a decent [dictionary](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/appreciate)?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent in German, I actually like to use the English phrase to sometimes express my thoughts to my German friends.

Comment: Without any specifics, there are dozens of valid answers. Please [edit] your question to specify a context, what aspects of “I appreciate it” are important to you, and how formal you want to be.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the question with more details, hopefully it's unambiguous now.

Comment: @guidot, from the dictionary you've linked the conclusion can be drawn that "etw zu schätzen wissen" is the translation. Judging from the answers, the conclusion is incorrect: the construct is very formal and not applicable in many situations where I would say "I appreciate it" in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The literal equivalent

> Ich weiß das zu schätzen.

belongs exclusively to a formal register in German, whereas the English original seems to be neutral in so far as it is applicable along a range of contexts.

Some formal ways to express gratitude:

> Ich bin Ihnen sehr zu Dank verpflichtet.
>   Ich bin Ihnen wirklich sehr dankbar.

Neutral:

> Danke.
>   Vielen Dank.
>   Danke schön.
>   Herzlichen Dank.

Informal (*'preciate it*):

> Das ist lieb.
>   Du bist ein Schatz/Engel. (Bist'n Schatz!)
>   Super. (Supi.)
>   Klasse.

Slang:

> Danke, Mann/Alter/Dicker.

Some of these involve literal thanks (*danke*), others function pragmatically in this manner (*super*).

Formal – informal is a bit of a crude distinction. For instance, in offices where people are generally friendly with each other, I find *Du bist ein Schatz!* pretty unsurprising (though more likely to be used by a woman).

Then there's dialect. In the region I grew up in, *merci* (pronounced in a German fashion with the accent on the first syllable and a vocalised r) was common.

Comment: Some of these need explanation (warnings) regarding when they would be appropriate. You can always use "Appreciate it." but personally I'd be piqued if a random stranger said "Danke, Dicker." or "Du bist ein Schatz." to me.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Where does “sehr nett von Ihnen/dir“ fall on the spectrum?

Comment: @raindev The "formula" seems to be *(das ist) (sehr) lieb/nett/freundlich (von Ihnen/dir)*. Which does not belong in the category of literal thanks and could be combined with such: *Vielen Dank, das ist sehr nett von Ihnen*. *Nett* feels more formal than *lieb* (but it also feels weird to make distinctions like that).

Comment: @raindev, be aware that *lieb* can be perceived as intimate or childish.

Comment: @DavidVogt, vielen dank, das ist sehr nett von Ihnen, meine Frage zu erklären.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich weiss es zu schätzen.

This is an interesting form. It is more formal than "I appreciate it."; it can  mean a big "thank you". Literally of course it means "I know how to *treasure* it"

(there is pretium = price in appreciate, too)

"Ich schätze es/ihn/sie" can also work, but it is not clear which kind of *schätzen* is meant.

```
?Ich schätze meine Gesundheit                 (health check? einschätzen?)
Ich schätze meine Gesundheit hoch ein         (=is important)
Ich weiss meine Gesundheit zu schätzen        (=appreciate)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example "I appreciate you walking the dog this morning, honey." you should use the phrase "Ich weiß es wirklich zu schätzen.".

**Ich weiß es wirklich zu schätzen, dass du heute Morgen mit dem Hund Gassi gegangen bist, Liebling.** (I really appreciate that you took the dog for a walk this morning, darling.) This sounds nice too. It sounds like you really mean it.

There are other ways to use the phrase `Ich schätze` (I appreciate):

- "Ich schätze es sehr..." or "Ich schätze es wirklich..." can also be used to signify appreciating something or not appreciating something.

Examples of usage:

- "...ich schätze es sehr, wie er etwas anpackt, wie er denkt, wie er arbeitet." - *Homo Faber von Max Frisch* (...I really appreciate how he tackles something, how he thinks, how he works.)
- "Ich schätze es wirklich nicht, unter Zeitdruck arbeiten zu müssen..." - *Unergründliches Universum von Dolores Cannon* (I really don't appreciate having to work under time pressure...)

Comment: Danke, ich weiß Ihre Antwort wirklich zu schätzen! What about the concerns the others expressed regarding "schätzen" being too formal?